# Map with initial values in abstract class

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an abstract class which holds some default values as follows

**BaseRequest.kt**

```kotlin
abstract class BaseRequest {

    abstract val route: String

    /** Initially, all requests contain the route param, that's why it has to be added for all requests */
    val baseMap: Map<String, String> by lazy { mapOf("route" to route) }

    abstract fun toMap(): Map<String, String>
}
```

Now, for all subclasses, I need anyone who extends the `BaseRequest` class to override the `toMap()` function and return a map that has an initial value of `route` that was initialized in the base class.

What I mean by that is that once the user overrides the map and fill it in with any values, I add a default value to these values.

**For example**

**ItemRequest.kt**

```kotlin
class ItemsRequest: BaseRequest() {

    override val route: String = "items"

    override fun toMap(): Map<String, String>  = mapOf("id" to "7")

}
```

For the `ItemsRequest` class, I need the returned map from `toMap()` function to have the `id` as well as the default `route` without having to manually add it in each subclass.

Is this possible?

Comment: In your first code snippet, is `ROUTE` just a placeholder for the actual value in your code for the sake of the question?

Comment: @ChrisGong yes, I edited it for clarity

Comment: And can we assume that any key-value pairs in the map from the `toMap` method won't redefine/override key-value pairs in `baseMap`?

Comment: Basically, `baseMap` was a try to implement what I'm trying to do but It didn't work. So, it can be modified or eliminated based on the proposed approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just simply combine the map that the subclass intends to return with the `baseMap` variable from the superclass. Since you said from your comments that the original `baseMap` can be modified, you can simply use the plus operation between `baseMap` and whatever other map that you want your specific subclass to return like so,

```
override fun toMap(): Map<String, String>  = baseMap + mapOf("id" to "7")
```

Note how `baseMap` is on the left side of the plus operation. In this case, if any keys exist in both `baseMap` and the map to the right of the plus operation, then the final map returned from `toMap` will only contain the values from the map on the right side of the plus operation for the keys common to both maps. If you want the `baseMap` key value pairs to take precedence and always be returned from any map returned from any subclass' `toMap` method, then have `baseMap` on the right side of the plus operation like so,

```
override fun toMap(): Map<String, String>  = mapOf("id" to "7") + baseMap
```

However, assuming that you want every subclass' `toMap` implementation to return at least the `baseMap`, it can be pretty redundant to constantly write `baseMap + ...` or `... + baseMap` over and over again for each subclass that overrides this `toMap` method. Therefore, my suggestion would be to make the `toMap` function in the parent class a non abstract function and define a different abstract function just for returning a map custom to classes derived from the parent class. Here's what I mean by that,

```
abstract class BaseRequest {

    abstract val route: String

    /** Initially, all requests contain the route param, that's why it has to be added for all requests */
    val baseMap: Map<String, String> by lazy { mapOf("route" to route) }

    abstract fun subMap(): Map<String, String>

    // again, up to you with how you want to combine the two maps, 
    // assuming you are okay with key-value pairs being overwritten by one of the maps, 
    // the plus operation is fine
    fun toMap(): Map<String, String> = baseMap + subMap()
}

class ItemsRequest: BaseRequest() {

    override val route: String = "items"

    override fun subMap(): Map<String, String>  = mapOf("id" to "7")

}
```

Note that the `subMap` function can also be a variable as well like how you did the `route` variable. And now, the `toMap` function for each derived class of `BaseRequest` will return a combination of `baseMap` and `subMap()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the `subMap` approach is what I was looking for.